# Storing SHA-512 Hashes in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, security

I was wondering if I use PHP's hash() function to generate sha512 hashes how would my MySQL table field look like in-order to be capable of holding the hashed password.

Here is my current MySQL password field layout

```
char(40)
```

Comment: Review the MySQL reference manual section on "Data types" : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-types.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A sha512 hash is represented as a **128 characters-long string**.

For example, the following portion of code :

```
$sha512 = hash('sha512', "Hello, World!");
echo strlen($sha512);
```

Will give this output :

```
128
```

Which means your `char(40)` is far too small, and that you should use a `char(128)`.

Another solution would be to store it in a binary form, and not a string -- which would mean 64 bytes.

But note it might be harder to deal with that representation, in some cases, I suppose.

Comment: Can you explain where you got 64 bytes from?  I'm trying to understand the math.

Comment: a sha512 is represented as 128 hexadecimal characters ; when using hexadecimal, you use two digits to represent one byte (from 0x00 to 0xFF) ; so, to store a binary value that can be represented by 128 hexadecimal characters, you need 64 bytes, if storing it as binary, and not hexadecimal text.